# How many UIDs are possible in Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I know that there are a number of system user IDs and a number of UIDs that corresponds to user applications. So I have the following questions:

1. How many system UIDs are there on Android? And what is the range of
   these UIDs?
2. What is the maximum number of applications UIDs are there? What is the
   range (I know that all application UIDs start from 10000)

Comment: You are welcome to read the source code and attempt to determine this. Bear in mind that, since all of this behavior is undocumented, whatever you find out may be wrong for some devices with modified firmware and may be wrong in the future as Android evolves.

Comment: Of course, I can read tons of source codes but it will take a lot of time. I ask this because I guess that somebody has already interested in this question. Maybe someone can point me where to search more precisely. However, you can help me with your activity in this question to get the fight answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h), 0 is for root (obviously), UIDs 1000-9999 (from `AID_SYSTEM` to `AID_NOBODY`) are reserved by the system. And as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) says, the range of UIDs, reserved for user applications is 10000-99999 (from `FIRST_APPLICATION_UID` to `LAST_APPLICATION_UID`).

**Upd:** [Since Android 4.1.1](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Process.java/?v=diff&id2=4.0.4_r2.1) the range of UIDs, reserved for user applications is 10000-19999.

Comment: +1 for linking the header and documentation. I don't know if/when it changed, but LAST_APPLICATION_UID seems to be 19999 instead of 99999.

Comment: Yes, it was changed in Android 4.1.1. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are 4 byte integers.  Not sure signed or not - in any case there is there is a enough of them ;)

Comment: No, I think you are not right. It seems to me that the upper bound is 65535. So you can see that they are not integer. However, I need precise values or where I can see them